# Magento 2 - Reviews - Product Reviews - created_at value is not getting as in database

Tags: magento2, product-review

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_reviewsColFactory = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");
$_storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$reviewsCollection = $_reviewsColFactory->create()
                                        ->addStoreFilter($_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId())
                                        ->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                                        ->setDateOrder();
<?php foreach($reviewsCollection as $review):?>
<?php echo $review['review_id'];  ?>----<?php echo $review['created_at'];  ?><br/>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

$review['created_at'] is not getting the value that is present in database.

Comment: **Solution:**  $formatDate = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface'); Inside loop add code echo $review['review_id']."--".$formatDate->formatDateTime($review['created_at']); After this created_at will be same as in database

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue in your other code, I have used your code and it is working fine see below code and result.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_reviewsColFactory = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");
$_storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$reviewsCollection = $_reviewsColFactory->create()
                                        ->addStoreFilter($_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId())
                                        ->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                                        ->setDateOrder();
foreach($reviewsCollection as $review):
echo 'Review Id =>', $review['review_id']; echo ' | Review Date =>', $review['created_at']; echo '<br/>'; 
endforeach;

die('called');
```

And result :

[image: review image]

I hope it helps!

Comment: Can you please check with the database table?

Comment: the created_at value displayed through the script above and database table value is different, that is an issue

Comment: See this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160135/date-displays-wrong

Comment: this is your issue.

Comment: yes i know the issue is related to timezone but how would you implement in the above script