# M2 | How to configure store's timezone to set date as I am getting wrong date in magento?

Tags: magento2, date, timezone

I get different date from todays date. I tried below ways and all give difference in time:

1)

```
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $contexts,
..........
..........

        $this->_timezone = $contexts->getLocaleDate();
..........
..........
$this->_timezone->date()->format('Y-m-d');
```

2)

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime */
$dateTime = $obj->create(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime::class);

$currentDate = $dateTime->gmtDate();
```

3)

```
 \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
```

As answered [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160135/date-displays-wrong), times are store in the database as UTC (+0:00). How can we set it to get correct date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the right time as per my clock from magento as below:

->Configured Timezone from Magento Backend

> Stores -> Configuration -> General ->Locale Options -> Timezone to
>   reflect "Gulf Standard Time (Asia/Dubai)"

as per the store location.

-> Got current date and time with

```
public function __construct(
          ...............
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $contexts,
        .....................
    )
{

        $this->_timezone = $contexts->getLocaleDate();
}

public function myFunctionName(){

    return $nowDateTime = $this->_timezone->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get current UTC datetime:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime
 */
$dateTime->date();
```

Get current datetime in store timezone:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone
 */
$timezone->date(new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Note that all datetimes stored in Magento database are in UTC.

To debug your store datetime, you can try this code:

```
$currentPhpDateTime = new \DateTime();

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime
 */
$currentMagentoDateTime = $dateTime->date();

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone
 */
$currentLocalizedMagentoDateTime = $timezone->date($currentPhpDateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

dump($currentPhpDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // output: current datetime in UTC
dump($currentMagentoDateTime); // output: current datetime in UTC
dump($currentLocalizedMagentoDateTime); // output: current datetime in timezone you set in Magento configuration
```

You will see something similar to these outputs:

```
"2019-08-28 00:00:00"
"2019-08-28 00:00:00"
"2019-08-28 07:00:00"
```

The first and second outputs are current date in UTC. The third one is current date in timezone you set in Magento configuration.

Note that date constructed using `new \DateTime()` is in UTC, because Magento set your default timezone to UTC while bootstraping the app. In Magento 2.3.2, you can see how Magento set your default timezone in file `app/bootpstrap.php` line 73:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: What is $now? $currentPhpDateTime?

Comment: @Tschallacka updated the answer, $now should be $currentPhpDateTime, which is instance of DateTime